# Custom Cell and Button

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

There is a custom cell in it button. By clicking on it, it becomes selected/unselected. But in the TableView by clicking on the button in the first cell I need to reset selected on the others. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's easy to resolve your problem with using delegate.

Create somewhere protocol kinda:

```
@protocol CustomCellDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void)handleSelection:(NSIndexPath) indexPath;
@end
```

In your custom cell's class create properties and func:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <CustomCellDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath;

- (void) handleTap
{
   [self.delegate handleSelection:self.selectedIndexPath];
}
```

Then in your view controller's class become subscriber for CustomCellDelegate and add property of "selected" indexPath:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSIndexPath *currentlySelectedIP;

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    // your custom cell stuff
     customCell.selected = NO;
     customCell.delegate = self;
     [customCell.yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     customCell.selectedIndexPath == indexPath;
     if (self.currentlySelectedIP != nil) && (self.currentlySelectedIP == indexPath) 
     {
        customCell.selected = YES; // handle stuff for selected cell/button, whatever
      }
  }
```

and handle delegate's function:

```
- (void) handleSelection:(NSIndexPath) indexPath
{
  self.currentlySelectedIP == indexPath;
  [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your need is to reset all the buttons, on tapping any table cell button then at any time there is only one button selected. Then you can keep reference to the selected table cell in controller and reset it.

If you want to reset all buttons, on tapping first row cell button, Then get all visible cells and reset for that cells. All other cell should be reset on returning cell view from datasource method.

You need to implement delegate, to get notification of button tap on any cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all cell from UITableView. Once you get all cells from UITableView, you can easily get all subviews from cell and reset button from it.

Comment: How i can get all cell?

Comment: NSArray *cells = [tableView visibleCells]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

1. When user taps on any button first deselect all buttons.
2. Then select the button that you've tapped.

Here is the code. This should be written in your custom cell's button tap method.

```
for (UIView *theView in self.subviews)
{
    if ([theView isKindOfClass:[UIView class]])
    {
        for (UIButton *theButton in theView.subviews)
        {
            if ([theButton isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
            {
                [theButton setSelected:NO];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You need clickable button in tableview last cell or first cell?

Comment: clickable all cells, but where iam tap on button in first cell, selected buttons other cells reset

Answer (score 0):

put This into your cellforrowatindex method

```
if([totalcheckmarkArray containsObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(int)indexPath.row]])
{
    [cell.btnCheckbox  setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"chk_check"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else
{
    [cell.btnCheckbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"chk_uncheck"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

cell.btnCheckbox.tag=indexPath.row;
[cell.btnCheckbox addTarget:self action:@selector(checkBoxClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Now When button clicked at particular position you need to call below method..

```
#pragma mark CheckBox Actions

-(void)checkBoxClicked:(id)sender{
UIButton *tappedButton = (UIButton*)sender;
int totalSection = (int)self.tableview.numberOfSections;
int totalRow = 0;
if (tappedButton.tag==0) {

        [totalcheckmarkArray removeAllObjects];
        [indexarray removeAllObjects];
        SelectedCateCount=0;
    NSLog(@"%d",SelectedCateCount);
}
else {
    if([tappedButton.currentImage isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"chk_check"]])
    {
        SelectedCateCount-=1;
        [totalcheckmarkArray removeObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(int)tappedButton.tag]];
        [indexarray removeObject:[arrSelectedCategory objectAtIndex:tappedButton.tag]];
    }
    else
    {
        SelectedCateCount+=1;
        [totalcheckmarkArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(int)tappedButton.tag]];
        [indexarray addObject:[arrSelectedCategory objectAtIndex:tappedButton.tag]];
    }
    NSLog(@"%d",SelectedCateCount);
    if (SelectedCateCount==arrSelectedCategory.count-1) {
        CellCategory *cell = (CellCategory *)[self.tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
        [cell.btnCheckbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"chk_check"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [totalcheckmarkArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(int)cell.btnCheckbox.tag]];
    }
    else{
        CellCategory *cell = (CellCategory *)[self.tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
        [cell.btnCheckbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"chk_uncheck"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [totalcheckmarkArray removeObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(int)cell.btnCheckbox.tag]];
    }
}
[_tableview reloadData];
NSLog(@"%@",indexarray);
}
```

now according to your requirement change in checkbox clicked method